# Extract text with different delimiters

Tags: perl, unix, text-files, delimiter

my textfile looks like this

```
foo.en 14 :: xyz 1;foo bar 2;foofoo 5;bar 9
bar.es 18 :: foo bar 4;kjp bar 2;bar 6;barbar 8
```

**Ignoring text before the `::` delimiter, is there a one liner unix command (many pipes allowed) or one liner perl script that extract the text such that yields the output of unique words delimited by `;` ?**:

```
xyz
foo bar
foofoo
bar
kjp bar
barbar
```

i've tried looping through the textfile with a python script but i'm looking for a one-liner for the task.

```
ans = set()
for line in open(textfile):
  ans.add(line.partition(" :: ")[1].split(";").split(" ")[:-1])

for a in ans:
  print a
```

Comment: i've done it with python and looping through the text file. i'm just looking for a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Perl:

```
perl -nle 's/.*?::\s*//;!$s{$_}++ and print for split /\s*\d+;?/' input
```

**Description**:

```
s/.*?::\s*//;  # delete up to the first '::'
```

This part:

```
!$s{$_}++ and print for split /\s*\d+;?/
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
foreach my $word (split /\s*\d+;?/) {   # for split /\s*\d+;?/
  if (not defined $seen{$word}}) {      # !$s{$_}
    print $word;                        # and print
  }
  $seen{$word}++;                       # $s{$_}++
}
```

Since the increment in `!$s{$_}++` is a post increment, Perl first test for the false condition and then does the increment. An undefined hash value has the value `0`. If the test fails, i.e., `$s{$_}` was previously incremented, then the **and** part is skipped due to [short circuiting](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=301355).

Comment: as much as i love perl, @Floris won the pipe award. Don't worry you're second in place if i get to allow 2 ans =)

Comment: :) just compare the outputs

Comment: they all gave the same output. @perreal wont the no-pipe award, lolz

Comment: I would probably vote for this answer if I could figure out how it works... but no explanation given. `!$s{$_}++ and print for split` ???!!! I'm sure it's clever - I wish I was, too.

Comment: @Floris, I added some description, hope it is sufficient.

Comment: It sure did. You got your +1!

Answer (score 2):

```
cat textfile | sed 's/.*:://g' |  tr '[0-9]*;' '\n' | sort -u
```

Explanation:

```
sed 's/.*:://g'      Take everything up to and including `::` and replace it with nothing
tr '[0-9];' '\n'     Replace numbers and semicolon with newlines
sort -u              Sort, and return unique instances
```

it does result in a sorted output, I believe...

Comment: also problem is `foo bar` won't be output, it would have output `foo` and `bar` for `foo bar`

Comment: @2er0 - you are right on both counts - Thanks! I saw you made an edit at the same time I was editing to correct the mistake of (foo bar)... I added the sort and think it's now correct.

Comment: The `grep -o -E '\(.*\);'` don't seem to be right. is it supposed to be `grep -o -E '\(.*\)\;'`

Comment: Simplified the last grep and two `seds` away with a `tr` command, and combined the sort and uniq. Bit more compact now

Comment: Thanks @sputnick. I guess that means you think I'm smoking? Or smoking something? ...

Comment: I'm sarcastic. 4 (before edit) unix pipes to do it is a lot =)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$ awk -F ' :: ' '{print $2}' input.txt | grep -oP '[^0-9;]+' | sort -u
bar 
barbar 
foo bar 
foofoo 
kjp bar 
xyz
```

If your phrases contains numbers, try this [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) regex:  `'[^;]+?(?=\s+\d+(;|$))'`

Answer (score 1):

With only [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk -F' :: ' '{
    gsub(/[0-9]+/, "")
    split($2, arr, /;/ )
    for (a in arr) arr2[arr[a]]=""
}
END{
    for (i in arr2) print i
}' textfile.txt
```

And a one-liner version :

```
 awk -F' :: ' '{gsub(/[0-9]+/, "");split($2, arr, /;/ );for (a in arr) arr2[arr[a]]="";}END{for (i in arr2) print i}' textfile.txt
```